# Summary or running total of array elements

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am creating a invoice printing system using Crystal Reports XI, where I get item details and quantity from database but item rate is entering by the end use as a comma separated parameter field. I am able to show rate with their corresponding item. I also able to calculate the item-value. but I am not able to calculate the total of the item-value. I am sharing the formula which I am using.

For Serial Number @SL=>

```
numberVar numSlno = 0;
IF PREVIOUSISNULL({ICTRED.ITEMDESC}) THEN
numSlno := 1
ELSE
numSlno := numSlno + 1
```

For Unit Price @unitPrice=>

```
IF {?UnitPrice}<>"" THEN
ToNumber(Split({?UnitPrice},",")[INT({@SL})])
```

For Item-Value @ItemValue

```
{ItemTable.qnty}*{@unitPrice}
```

Now I am trying to get the summary of @ItemValue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, I used three-formula trick for @ItemValue and its working.